# SQL Server 2005 - Same query, same server, two different execution plans

Tags: sql, indexing

I've been fighting with an ongoing issue on our server for a few weeks now. There is a simple query that gets run in several different stored procedures, but in a few of them, the query can take nearly 4 minutes to run. Some procedures have this exact same query and they run in < 1 second.  Running it from a query window returns in < 1 second.

I cannot recreate this - I can't run the procedure the user is running (because it changes data), and the problem does not arise on our test server.  I can sometimes recompile (F5) the procedure, which seems to recreate the execution plan, and fix it for a while, but it always returns.

The query is as simple as:

```
SELECT '1' 
FROM TRANSACTION_LOG WITH (NOLOCK) 
WHERE TYPE = 15 AND SERIAL_NO = @P_TRAVELER_SERIAL
```

- `TRANSACTION_LOG` has ~90m rows
- `TYPE` has a non-clustered index
- `SERIAL_NO` has a non-clustered index

After some research and profiler capturing, I found something odd in the execution plan. I managed to capture the execution plan while it was running quickly and another when it was running slowly.  These are from the exact same procedure, exact same query - the only difference would be the value of the `@P_TRAVELER_SERIAL` parameter:

FAST:

```
Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1005]=CASE WHEN [Expr1006] THEN (1) ELSE (0) END))          
  |--Nested Loops(Left Semi Join, DEFINE:([Expr1006] = [PROBE VALUE]))
    |--Constant Scan
    |--Filter(WHERE:([MICS].[dbo].[Transaction_Log].[TYPE]=(15)))
      |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Bmk1000], [Expr1010]) WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH)
        |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([MICS].[dbo].[Transaction_Log].[IX_SERIAL_NO]), SEEK:([MICS].[dbo].[Transaction_Log].[SERIAL_NO]=[@P_TRAVELER_SERIAL]) ORDERED FORWARD)
        |--RID Lookup(OBJECT:([MICS].[dbo].[Transaction_Log]), SEEK:([Bmk1000]=[Bmk1000]) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD)
```

SLOW:

```
Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1005]=CASE WHEN [Expr1006] THEN (1) ELSE (0) END))
  |--Nested Loops(Left Semi Join, DEFINE:([Expr1006] = [PROBE VALUE]))
    |--Constant Scan 
    |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([MICS].[dbo].[Transaction_Log]), WHERE:([MICS].[dbo].[Transaction_Log].[TYPE]=(15) AND [MICS].[dbo].[Transaction_Log].[SERIAL_NO]=[@P_TRAVELER_SERIAL]))
```

Why would it use an index seek with one plan and a table scan with the other? It's the same query and the same procedure? Would table activity have anything to do with it? It's a busy table...

Thanks

Comment: does the index [Transaction_Log].[IX_SERIAL_NO]) exist on the "slow" database?

Comment: He said it was the same database.

Comment: Something is wrong with both plans.  The queries do not have any obvious joins in them.  Is Transaction_Log a view?

Comment: I'd like to see the schema for the Transaction_Log table (at least the two columns in question) and I'd like to know what values you're passing into the SERIAL_NO predicate (where clause).

Comment: TRANSACTION_LOG is not a view.  
TYPE is an INT, not null.    
SERIAL_NO is a CHAR(10), null.  It would be sending in values such as '1600000000' or 'EF123456'.   

@P_TRAVELER_SERIAL is a VARCHAR(10) parameter to the stored procedure that contains the problematic select statement.    

I should also add the select statement is in an IF statement:  

    `IF EXISTS (SELECT '1' FROM TRANSACTION_LOG WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE     TYPE = 15 AND SERIAL_NO = @P_TRAVELER_SERIAL)  
    BEGIN    
        SELECT '1002'  
        RETURN  
    END`

Comment: If performance is the main problem, what about just loading a subset of data from TRANSACTION_LOG into a table variable based on key values or dates or something else to define a range for the data? You'd get around having to hit the table for all but the initial select and whatever subsequent operations you line up. Otherwise, maybe check using profiler to see who or what is hitting the table at the same time, and see whether these maybe confer a different weight to these factors as far as the optimizer goes?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a parameter sniffing issue to me.  What happens is that over time SQL Server determines that the execution plan for your procedure is out of date, and the next time the procedure is executed a new plan is compiled.  Unfortunately when this happens, SQL server uses the currently passed in value(s) when determining what plan to generate (and cache) for the procedure.  If the value(s) that were passed in at that time happen to be uncommon enough, SQL Server may build, and subsequently cache, an execution plan that does a table scan.  While  this may be optimal for the uncommon value that was passed in, it's clearly not so ideal for a value that would benefit from an index seek.

For more info and possible workarounds, see this technet blog post.
http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx